# How to create a receipt-like paper background in Objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am creating an iPhone app that I feel needs to have a receipt background on the landing tab. Mint has this on their mobile app for both Android and iOS. I can't for the life of me think of how I would do this without drawing and duplicating a bunch of triangles on the bottom of a white container.

The attached image should show you what I'm aiming to do.

EDIT: It appears I can't attach an image. Go here - http://dl.dropbox.com/u/189423/photo.PNG

**UPDATE**: I have decided to use an image - Now, how would I go about using a custom image for the top, tiling along the y-axis for the content area, and then another on the bottom? As far as I can tell, a UIView only allows for one background image. Any help?

Comment: Have a look at http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/06/extracting-images-from-apps-in-the-appstore/ This describes how to use "appcrush", an excellent utility that allows you to see the images of any app. If you use it with Mint, you might get a good understanding of how it is implemented.

Comment: Taking a look now, thanks for the tip! I'll update with what I find.

Comment: I can't find the exact image for that screen, but it appears that they use an image for the tear look. one normal and one @2x - I will give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have images for:

1. Top cell of the tableView
2. Middle cells
3. Bottom cell of the tableview

and set them as backgroundView for each cell.

If your tableView doesnt grow then you can have single image set as tableView backgorund

Comment: So, you would just have that teared paper look be an image? One way on top and flipped on bottom? This would work, I suppose, provided I didn't allow rotating, and specified different images for the iPad version. I was hoping to find a scalable solution. Thanks for the tip, I'll see if I can give it a go.

Comment: good point...you could also draw a strip with triangle at the top/bottom along the length of the cell as background. That I guess would help if the cell width needs expanding

Comment: I'm toying with that now, as I'm looking into what Yann suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use a background UIImage, with bounds set for tiling. The triangles at the bottom are likely just using the image alpha channel.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the 'bounds set for tiling' option. Would this allow me to have 1 triangle repeated along the x axis of this space?